# Passport - Problema al NO pasar el token en método logout

Tags: laravel, passport, laravel-8

Estoy creando una APi en Laravel 8, instale passport para los token, mi problema comienza cuando en el método logout del AuthController al momento de NO pasar el token el sistema se cae y da un error 405

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Curiosamente el error me reclama por la ruta de método login (route::post) argumentando que no soporta una acción get. Este es el api.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito controlar ese error en caso que el usuario no pase el token en la petición.

Las pruebas de la api las realizo con Insomnia.

Comment: Recuerda que El código se comparte como texto

Answer (score 1):

Yo solo llamo el token en el head del proyecto. Ejemplo:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

De esta manera solo se utiliza una sola vez.

Comment: Los tokens de los que habla son de passport no?

Comment: Los token los genero con passport y es una API sin front hasta el momento, las pruebas las hago con insomnia